# Comment nommer quelqu'un qui respecte les choses (la loi, le code de la route, etc.)

Tags: demande-de-mot

Aujourd'hui, j'ai voulu dire la phrase "*en tant que respecteur du code de la route, (...)*", qui est fausse.

Je savais bien que le mot "**respecteur**" n'existait pas, mais je n'avais rien trouvé de mieux.

De fait, **quel mot** j'aurais pu utiliser **à la place** ? Éventuellement, quelle tournure de phrase plus jolie que "en tant que quelqu'un qui respecte le code de la route" j'aurais pu utiliser ?

Edit : idéalement, j'aimerais un **nom**, plutôt qu'un adjectif.

Answer (score 5):

On peut dire :

> Respectueux du code de la route, ...

Comment: C'est pas mal effectivement, mais je préfèrerais un nom plutôt qu'un adjectif (j'ai édité ma question pour les futures réponses).

Answer (score 4):

On peut donner cette idée en employant l'adjectif *bon* avec toutes sortes de nom.  *Un bon conducteur*, sous-entendu qui respecte le code de la route, *un bon citoyen*, qui respecte les lois, *un bon mari*, sa femme, *un bon fils*, ses parents, etc.

Comment: Oui, *un bon élève* aussi.

Comment: Ne pas tromper sa femme n'est pas le seul  critère qui définit un *bon* mari.

Comment: @Toto  C'est vrai, j'ai amendé ma réponse.

Answer (score 3):

Je n'ai pas l'impression qu'il existe un nom pour désigner ça, où alors il n'est jamais utilisé. Le plus naturel serait, selon moi, de dire :

"*en tant que personne respectueuse du code de la route, (...)*"

Answer (score 2):

Selon le sens souhaité, on met l'emphase sur la "personne" ou sur le "code de la route".
BBBreiz a donné une très bonne réponse avec l'observance du code de la route. "En tant que bon observateur du code de la route, ...".

Le plus habituel sera l'emploi de "conducteur **respectueux du code de la route**".

Pour utiliser un "nom", on pourra dire par métaphore en s'éloignant de l'usage courant : "en tant que **citoyen de la route**" ou "**conducteur diligent**".

Answer (score 1):

Je crois que garant ne correspond pas exactement au sens demandé. il me semble que l'on doit plutôt dire " **Observateur de la loi**". Notez que le mot "observateur" a 2 sens, l'un lié à "observation" et le second à "observance", qui est un sens abstrait et figuré de l'observation. L'observateur de la loi relève de l'observance.

Comment: *Observant* serait parfait, s'il n'était consacré par l'usage aux questions religieuses.

Answer (score 0):

**Garant** paraît approprié dans cette situation.

> En tant que **garant** du code de la route.

En tant que **responsable de sa propre conduite**.

Cette forme est toutefois **ambiguë** car il est difficile de déterminer le **niveau de responsabilité** du locuteur, là où le respect se limite généralement à la responsabilité personnelle.
Il s'agit donc plutôt d'une **forme à employer avec une personne proche**, qui a déjà une certaine estimation du niveau de responsabilité de celui qui l'emploie.

Dans cet exemple, l'interlocuteur pourrait également comprendre que celui qui emploie la phrase fait partie des forces de l'ordre ou travaille dans le domaine juridique.